# What exactly is Seagate's GoFlex product line and its advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I read a lot about Seagate's GoFlex, see some videos, see the product listings, but to be honest, its not ever clear to me what exactly they are trying to sell me.

So, is this simply external drives with propietary connectors that Seagate sells adapters for various other common connectors (USB, Firewire, eSATA)?

Who has these drives and likes them and uses the GoFlex portion and what situations or use cases should we consider these?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be another way to sell a portable hard drive.

"Upgradeable to firewire 800 and USB 3.0"

Who upgrades a portable hard drive? People hardly do that with PC's anymore. When it no longer meets your needs, you upgrade by purchasing a New and better model at a better price. Portable storage has been dropping in price for 10 years, so if you wait and buy it when you need it, its cheaper.

Why not just buy what you need at the time you need it.

I suppose this is marketing based on the new USB 3.0 that will be common place on PC's in a year or so. Firewire 800 has been around for many years and few people use it.

Upgrade cable for 3.0 is $20

"Plug and Play access and connectivity no other devices offer"

I did not see anything special did you?

Marketing hooplah imho.

I can't say much for the other GoFlex  media devices, there may be some good features with those.

.